# Building dependent packages with BitBake separately

Tags: continuous-integration, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

We have a collection of related, and partly interdependent, packages. They live in separate Git repositories. Like:

- `git@bitbucket.company:common`
- `git@bitbucket.company:libfoo`

  - depends on `common`
- `git@bitbucket.company:libbar`

  - depends on `common`
- `git@bitbucket.compnay:libbarex`

  - depends on `libbar`
- `git@bitbucket.company:daemon`

  - depends on `common`
- `final-image` (just an image recipe)

  - depends on `libfoo`, `libbar`, `libbarex`, `daemon`

The packages are currently built by setting up the Yocto environment, checking out all of them and running `bitbake` with the image target that depends on all of them. The checkout is done with logic containing special logic. That is

```
git clone https://git.yoctoproject.org/git/poky
git clone -b $BRANCH git@bitbucket.company:common
git clone -b $BRANCH git@bitbucket.company:libfoo
git clone -b $BRANCH git@bitbucket.company:libbar
git clone -b $BRANCH git@bitbucket.company:libbarex
git clone -b $BRANCH git@bitbucket.company:daemon
. poky/oe-init-build-env
../common/add-layers.sh
bitbake final-image
```

The disadvantage is that the CI server does not understand the configuration management side of things, so it can't do things like building each pull-request, not to mention reporting it back to the Git repository manager to gate the pull-requests on it.

So I would like to start splitting the build to build each package separately, pulling the dependencies according to some specification that shall be updated as needed.

But how do I do that?

I can add

```
bitbake -c populate_sdk final-image
```

to the main build, and then use the SDK to build individual components. However that means that any changes in `common` have to be merged, and the SDK rebuilt, before I can build `libfoo`, `libbar` or `daemon` and additionally changes to `libbar` have to be merged before I can build `libbarex`.

Can I push the results of these incremental builds to some kind of repository and pull them back to build the dependent component without having to rebuild the SDK?

Comment: We do have 2 types of builds in our CI, one job that builds the entire Yocto image and SDK, and one job for each home-packages. Each home-package job retrieves latest generated SDK and compiles code with it (+sonar, etc). Yocto build is launched daily with integrated stuff, but it doesn't use SDK compilated binaries, it does it from scratch too (but without static analysis etc). Hope it helps

Comment: @Nayfe, but do you have packages that depend on each other? I understand building of SDK, but if the packages depend on each other, I can't build the dependent package until the dependency is not only integrated, but also the rebuild is done.

Comment: If home-package A depends on another home-package B, we build B then A in A job. It's maybe not the best option but it works for us. You can also try to use extended SDK which allows the use of bitbake outside Yocto environment.

Comment: @Nayfe yeah, that's exactly what I am asking how to avoid. I am also not sure how far the extended SDK can get us; basically I would like to take the packages built by one build to build the dependent package (basically what a Debian cross-compilation environment would be doing), but while bitbake builds packages, I don't see a way to use them and the `do_populate_sysroot` is a separate step rather than `do_prepare_recipe_sysroot` simply extracting the packages of the dependencies.